# how to implement polling in below mentioned code. I want to poll data every 60 sec from the specified url. how can i do it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, highcharts

kindly help me to implement polling in below mentioned code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">Time series Highchart</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'   
        },
        series: [{}]
    };


    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {
               options.series[0].data = data;
               var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    }, 60000);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code which is hitting the rest api and giving the data on highchart. I want to implement the code so that it will show the data on highchart after polling for atleast 60 sec.

Comment: java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use the setInterval function: 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'   
    },
    series: [{}]
};
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        chart.series[0].setData(data);
     });
 }, 60000);
```

Edit: added chart update.

Comment: Can you please embedd this code inside my code as i am getting so much error.

Comment: @user8374049Abhi-Man tell me more, what are your errors ? Options must be defined elsewhere, with your exemple it seem this is a global object.

Comment: You can see my edit code should this is the right way to embedd your set interval code??

Comment: @user8374049Abhi-Man i'm not able to say if it is the better way but, it do what you asked. It is better to update, as d_paul said. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Right now, with this code, you create a new chart every 60 seconds. If you want only to update data on a chart, use Series.setData() or Series.update() instead.

```
chart.series[0].setData(data);
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1yfa9qkr/

Comment: Very close my solution. In jsFiddle Example, Instead of updating on console can it give updated data on highchart itself.

Comment: Sure. You can use renderer to to generate custom label (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label) and update its opacity each interval. Take a look at the example: http://jsfiddle.net/6qenpxo4/.

Comment: No sir. you got me wrong. I mean to say it should show updated data after polling on highchart. For example : http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB01PF84M   ----Live Random Data.

Comment: Are you talking about the animation showing the change in data? The setData() function has its own animation but you cannot see it now because data from the JSON is the same all the time. I modified previous demo, to show the process of updating data: http://jsfiddle.net/09jc90d2/.

Comment: No, I don't want the animation to be shown. I want that it should show real data after polling on highchart in continuously moving manner. I modified your code but in this code it is showing the data each time on new highchart but i want it to show on same highchart eachtime. -- jsfiddle.net/d0unockz     ....Please help me out.

Comment: @user8374049Abhi-Man check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)